# Why does "eval" not work inside While loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, eval

I am having a challenge parsing a variable using eval within my while loop.  Its processed outside the loop successfully using getops script.

```
script.sh -l foo1 ($OPT_L)
```

(within my script)

```
foo1=`shuf 1-10 -n 1`
eval LOCATION=\$$OPT_L
```

if I echo $LOCATION I will get a random value from 1 to 10 as expected.

Inside my loop,  I'm checking if the value of LOCATION exists and if a match is found, rerun the eval with another random number until USEDPORT is 0

The eval inside the loop is not working.

```
   USEDPORT=$(grep $LOCATION /home_vpn/*/lastport | wc -l)
    counter=1
    while [ $USEDPORT -ge 1 ] || [ $counter -lt 10 ] ; do
            echo "Port $LOCATION is being used $USEDPORT times"
            echo "Counter is $counter"
            echo "OPTL is $OPT_L"
            eval LOCATION=\$$OPT_L
            counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
    done
```

Script Output:

./vpn-ip-update-add.sh.new  -l foo1

Port 10004 is being used 1 times
Counter is 1
Port 10004 is being used 1 times
Counter is 2
Port 10004 is being used 1 times
Counter is 3
Port 10004 is being used 1 times
Counter is 4
Port 10004 is being used 1 times

Comment: ...mind you, it's certainly false to claim that `eval` doesn't work in a while loop. It'd be nice if the code in the question demonstrated that clearly, but it requires log files that nobody else will have, so it can't really be run outside the OP's local environment. (Also, it doesn't actually include the `getopts` code necessary to set `OPT_L`, or any stub code to set it by hand / simulate what getopts is doing).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval`: use indirect parameter expansion.

```
LOCATION=${!OPT_L}
```

Better yet, don't make internal variable names part of the external interface of your script.

Here is an example of a `case` statement that maps external arguments to internal values.

```
case $OPT_L in
  value1) LOCATION=location1 ;;
  value2) LOCATION=location2 ;;
  *) printf 'Invalid location %s\n' "$OPT_L"; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Appreciate the response,  see my response above (count not fit due to character limit in reply)